# In the figure below,three congurent semicircles with centres P,RQ,R are drawn on each side of three equilateral triangle.Find shaded part's area?

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

In the figure below,three congurent semicircles with centres P,RQ,R are drawn on each side of three equilateral triangle.Find shaded part's area?

Comment: If $x$ is the side of a triangle then $x/2+\sqrt{3}x/2=6$

Comment: Anything you didn't understand that made you not to accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The side of  a triangle $x={12\over \sqrt{3}+1}$ (Why? Check out the comment)

Shaded area $=18\pi-3({\sqrt{3}x^2\over 4}+\pi {x^2\over 8})$

Comment: @Joffan More filling up would be spoon feeding ..

Comment: @Joffan Thanks for the $\pi$. And I have defined my variable in a comment in the very beginning

Comment: @Joffan Done$\ $ !

Comment: Oh, whoops , $36\pi$ would be the whole circle.

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this from a multiple-choice perspective, the area of the semicircle overall is about
$$ 36\pi/2 \approx 18\cdot 3{\small\frac 17} = 56{\small\frac 47} = 3\times 18{\small\frac 67}$$

which we need to reduce by the $3$ "ice-cream cones" like $YTCZ$.

Then letting setting the radius of the small semicircles $w = |RC| = |RZ| = |YZ|/2$, we see $|YR| =  w\sqrt 3$ and $6 = w(1+\sqrt 3)$
with the area of  $YTCZ = w^2(\sqrt3 + \pi/2)$

Then $w$ is about $ \frac{6}{11/4} = 2\frac{2}{11}$, say $w^2 \approx 4.8, (\sqrt3 + \pi/2) \approx 3.3$ and area $YTCZ \approx 15.84$.

Then the shaded area $\approx 3 \times (18\frac 67 - 15.84) \approx 3\times 3 = 9 $

$\to$ choose answer **d**

(and you can get an exact number easily enough from this process also if needed - my 2dp answer is actually $8.76\text{ cm}^2$, not $8.74$)